# Incompatible type in if Statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, incompatibletypeerror

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivideTwo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    System.out.println("This program divides two numbers.");
    System.out.print("Enter the numerator: ");
    numerator = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the denominator: ");
    denominator = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print(numerator + "/" + denominator + " = ");
    if (denominator = 0)
    System.out.println("Division by zero is not allowed.");
    else
    System.out.println((double)numerator/denominator);
```

I'm getting a compile error with my if (denominator = 0) line saying that it's an incompatible type, please explain and help!

Comment: `=` is assignment operator. `==` is equality operator.

Comment: thank you! I forgot about that!

Comment: `if (denominator == 0)`!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use like

```
if (denominator == 0)
```

`==` for checking equality in primitive type, `=` for assigning value to variables.

And if statement requires a expression type of boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The single "=" is used to assign a value to a variable. Ex:

```
int Num = 0
```

The double "==" is used to compare one data type to the other Ex:

```
if(Num==0){}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @KugathasanAbimaran explains, you need to use `==` for testing equality, not `=`.

The reason for the "incompatible type" error is that `denominator = 0` is actually a valid expression whose value is `0`.  But the condition of an `if` statement requires an expression whose type is `boolean` ... and `0` is not a `boolean` value.

---

<sup>In fact, in C / C++, `if (denominator = 0)` is legal ... and *probably* a bug, assuming that you were actually just trying to test `denominator` against `0`. 'Cos what it *actually* does is to evaluate to `0` and assign `0` to `denominator.  Ouch!!!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are beginner ,

You Should to see [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)
to find the list of Java operators and there usage (meaning).
In Your code:

```
 if (denominator = 0)
System.out.println("Division by zero is not allowed.");
```

you are telling to your program that assign a value zero to denominator(int type), While if () condition operates on boolean value, for your purpose , you should to write

```
 if (denominator == 0)
System.out.println("Division by zero is not allowed.");
```

the '==' is known as equality operator and returns a boolean value (true if value is equal to the specified one, and false if the are not equal)